# How can I implement a thread-safe list wrapper in Delphi?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, semaphore, critical-section

I have a list wrapper that maintains two Tstringlists and a TClassList

I need this to be thread safe, such that:

- Concurrent writes are not allowed (wait state of some sort should be entered)
- Reading while writing (or vice versa) is not allowed (wait state of some sort should be entered)
- Concurrent reads *are* allowed

Any ideas on how I can do this? My instinct tells me it needs more than just a critical section, perhaps a semaphore or "usage counter", perhaps one of these in *conjunction* with a CS.

I'm just not quite sure where to start - anything from an overall approach in english to psuedo-code, to delphi implementation or external link would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should have a look at the TMultiReadExclusiveWriteSynchronizer class declared in sysutils.pas...

Comment: Probably the longest class name in the RTL :)

Comment: they could so easily have called it TMREWS

Comment: They could easily have called it TGreenIdea and conveyed as much information as TMREWS would. Don't be afraid of long identifier names.

Comment: @Steve It is called `TMREWSync`

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at this tutorial.
[Threading the Delphi Way](http://www.eonclash.com/Tutorials/Multithreading/MartinHarvey1.1/ToC.html)

Look at Chapter 11, but it's all good stuff.

Comment: Awesome Link. Could have used this when I was doing more in Delphi a few years ago!

Comment: The original link appears dead - I think it was the same as this [article by Martin Harvey](https://nickhodges.com/MultiThreadingInDelphi/ToC.html)

Answer (score 2):

You really should look at TThreadList.

The methods .Add, .Remove, .Clear automatically lock the list for you.  If needed, you can also lock/unlock as needed:

```
x.LockList; 
try 
  //do whatever
finally  
  x.Unlocklist; 
end;
```

TMultiReadExclusiveWriteSynchronizer is a grand idea but I don't know if they ever ironed all the bugs out.  It has always had issues under load.

Comment: That is not what the OP is wanting, as LockList() locks the list for exclusive access - parallel read access is therefore impossible.

Comment: I was completely unaware that TThreadList even existed until now. I had been using TStringList objects with all sorts of CriticalSections in my code. This will make life much simpler!